# Agile Toolkit: Password Change FormAndSave

Tags: php, frameworks, atk4

I have been following the Agile Toolkit "Book" and I have reached: http://agiletoolkit.org/learn/app/auth

I tried using the code provided:

```
class page_account extends Page {
    function init(){
        parent::init();

        $this->api->auth->check();

        $model = $this->add('Model_Customer');
        $model->getField('email')->system(true);
        $this->add('FormAndSave')->setModel($model)->loadData($this->api->auth->get('id'));
    }
}
```

But that just gave me a model not set error so knowing where FormAndSave derived from I changed the code to:

```
class page_account extends Page {
    function init(){
        parent::init();

        $this->api->auth->check();

        $model = $this->add('Model_Customer');

        $saveForm=$this->add('Form');

        $saveForm->setModel($model)->loadData($this->api->auth->get('id'));

        $saveForm->addSubmit();

        $saveForm->onSubmit(function($saveForm) {

        try {
            $saveForm->update()->js()->univ()->successMessage('Saved changes.')->execute();
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            $saveForm->js()->univ()->alert('Failed to save.')->execute();
        }
});

    }
}
```

This at least lets me save the data but I cannot get the password field to show up. I can add it to the model right after by:

```
$model = $this->add('Model_Customer');
$model->addField('password', 'password');
```

The problem is that shows the hashed password (obviously heh) and adding ->system(true) just makes it invisible. This is the Model_Customer:

```
class Model_Customer extends Model_Table {
    public $table='customer';

    function init() {
        parent::init();

        $this->addField('name');
        $this->addField('email');
    }
}
```

Help would be super appreciated - with some explanation would be great, I'm learning this framework and the more I can learn the better.

Currently the form does not show the password field for the user to edit his/her password - how do I go about implementing that functionality? Like I said I can have the field show up if I add it again to the model but it shows the hashed password which is really not what you want. How do I do this properly folks?

Thanks!

**Update: I have it working but not sure if this is the correct or secure way:**

```
    class page_account extends Page {
    function init(){
        parent::init();

        $this->api->auth->check();

        $auth=$this->api->auth;

        $model = $this->add('Model_Customer');

        $model->addField('password')->type('password');

        $saveForm=$this->add('MVCForm');

        $saveForm->setModel($model)->loadData($this->api->auth->get('id'));

        $saveForm->set('password', '');

        $saveForm->addSubmit();

        if($saveForm->isSubmitted()){

            // Short-cuts
            $auth=$this->api->auth;
            $l=$saveForm->get('email');
            $p=$saveForm->get('password');

            if ($p) {
                // Manually encrypt password
                $enc_p = $auth->encryptPassword($p,$l);
                $saveForm->set('password', $enc_p);
            } else {
                $saveForm->set('password', $model->get('password'));
            }

            $saveForm->update()->js()->univ()->successMessage('Saved user information. ')->execute();
        }
    }
}
```

This creates an empty field for the password that only updates if you put something in it.

Comment: I see something that resembles an implied question, but it needs to be asked explicitly.  Mentioning what you expect the code to do would also help.

Comment: And also sorry @BenBarden question has been stated much more clearly now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think is is the right way to do it, though hard to be sure. It does work and I can't see any security issues with it.

```
class page_account extends Page {
    function init(){
        parent::init();

        $this->api->auth->check();

        $auth=$this->api->auth;

        $model = $this->add('Model_Customer');

        $model->addField('password')->type('password');

        $saveForm=$this->add('MVCForm');

        $saveForm->setModel($model)->loadData($this->api->auth->get('id'));

        $saveForm->set('password', '');

        $saveForm->addSubmit();

        if($saveForm->isSubmitted()){

            // Short-cuts
            $auth=$this->api->auth;
            $l=$saveForm->get('email');
            $p=$saveForm->get('password');

            if ($p) {
                // Manually encrypt password
                $enc_p = $auth->encryptPassword($p,$l);
                $saveForm->set('password', $enc_p);
            } else {
                $saveForm->set('password', $model->get('password'));
            }

            $saveForm->update()->js()->univ()->successMessage('Saved user information. ')->execute();
        }
    }
}
```